# Error while passing test data point to sci-kit learn <endpoint>.predict() function created inside AWS-Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I created a scikit learn model endpoint inside AWS Sagemaker. I want to make predictions on my test set using this endpoint. My endpoint creation code looks like

```
predictor = sklearn.deploy(1, 'ml.m4.xlarge')
from sagemaker.predictor import csv_serializer
predictor.content_type = 'text/csv'
predictor.serializer = csv_serializer
predictor.deserializer = None
```

When I pass my test data point as a list  `predictor.predict(l)` where `l` is the list, it throws an error

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
```

When I pass it as a numpy array of 2 dimensions(I checked dimensions using .ndim), it still throws the same error. When I tried to pass the data as a string separated by commas without any spaces, it still throws the same error.

```
 Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

This line gets displayed every time the `Valueerror` is thrown but even after reshaping, the same error persists.

So I have tried the formats `'2,3,4,5'`, `['2,3,4,5']`, `array[[2,3,4,5]]`,`[2,3,4,5]` but none of these work.
Can someone please convey what the right format is for the input to the predictor function of sci-kit learn?

Comment: Have you tried np.array([2, 3, 4, 5]) as well? That is the format if I have one-dimensional input. Logically, your input dimensions depend on your model (number of features).

Comment: We tried that format and its throwing the same error

Comment: Have you trained your model? The format of the array for predict should have the same format as the array used for training input.

Comment: Yes. I trained my model. There is model.tar.gz file inside my s3 bucket

Comment: I would suggest you use the same array you used for training (X_train or so) for prediction. This should work. Just as a check for the format.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having problems with your input dimensions? Users are able to implement their own input_fn in order to help with debugging as well. I suggest you try printing the deserialized input when it is passed to the inference call to see where you might be having trouble with the dimension size.